# Changes in Real Solar size around 1979?

Tags: solar-terrestrial-physics, astronomy

Has been observed any changes in the real sun´s size on ocassion of the 1979 solar storm event ? (after and before)

Comment: This is a question for astronomy stack exchange, but the short answer is no, the sun is not actively changing size.  You might enjoy this site: http://solar-center.stanford.edu/FAQ/Qshrink.html

Comment: I'm in the naive category, haven't heard of this... what information has suggested to you that it might have luis?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Astronomy.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no such changes have been observed. Laclare et al. (1996) summarize various published solar diameter data from observations made between 1970 and 1995. Here's Figure 6 from their paper.

[image: solar diameter variations]

As you can see (and as Laclare et al. point out), solar semi-diameter has shown no significant variation during the measurement periods. Given their deviation from the other data sets, the Wittmann data seem rather suspect, but even they show absolutely no change between the 1972 and 1981 data points. In short, none of these data are consistent with the notion that solar diameter changed in 1979.

---

**References**

Laclare, F., Delmas, C., Coin, J. P., & Irbah, A. (1996). Measurements and variations of the solar diameter. *Solar Physics*, 166(2), 211-229.